# Update ADT from 21.0 to 21.1

Tags: java, android, api, sdk, adt

i downloaded APIs 15,16 and 17. After the download is finished, I closed eclipse but when i open it again it gives me a message box saying I need to update my ADT from 21.0.0 into 21.1 or higher, (and my current project suddenly didnt work, and full of red lines). There is a "Check for Updates" button. But after clicking it, it says there was no update found. I asked Google and found out that there is already ADT 21.1 released. I am wondering if I should just download the latest ADT bundle, but also looking for a quicker solution. I said “quicker” because my internet connection is a bit slow. :( It will take me a whole day to finish the download. :( And also after i downloaded the API, my graphical layouts do not show any more. There is a message saying "Eclipse is loading the SDK. Home.xml will refresh automatically once the process is finished." I waited for eternity, but nothing shows up. Im pretty messed up here. My project does not work anymore, although it worked well before i downloaded the APIs. Can anyone help me?. Thanks.

Comment: One thing I have learned is never update a stable working adt!
You never know what surprises might come with the update, and don't use the adt bundle it is too buggy download Juno eclipse and install the adt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to eclipse > help > Check for updates.

It should list the latest update of adt. If it doesn't work, try this :

go to eclipse > help > Install new software

Click on add

add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

It will list the updates available- which should ideally be adt 21.1.0 (latest)

install the latest adt and everything should be fine.

Comment: Google could have pointed this out… Better yet, why don't they include the most recent ADT version in their fancy Eclipse+ADT bundle?

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me, here's what I did-

Apparently, the SDK updated to version 21.1, but ADT, still at 21.0. 21.1 is currently a preview release (so I'm not sure how we accidentally updated the sdk...), so you have to manually add the update source. There's a nice guide (http://tools.android.com/preview-channel), but here's what you need:

Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
Click the "Add" button, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Previews" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse-preview/
Click OK.

If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.

This worked for me, although I would rather have just downgraded the sdk. 
Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

go to `window -> SDK manager`  and then install `Android SDK Tools` to 21.1 and then check for updates again.

I used to get error " update cannot be installed " for that run eclipse in Admin permission.

Comment: if this wont help, follow another answer given by Inankupeli .

Answer (score 0):

same with your problem !!!
btw, Thanks for the info ! I tried it after read this and wohooow It worked ! thx

1. go to eclipse > help > Install new software
2. click on add
3. add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/