# Update Android ADT Tool to 21.1.0 from 21.0.1

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

i have updated SDK to 21.1 and how to update ADT 21.1 in old version. and when i opened my SDK it displays

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0 or above.  Current version is 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58.  Please update ADT to the latest version.

any solution, Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer in the below link can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022622/eclipse-adt-update-does-not-work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Faced the same problem and success with following steps

1. Download the ADT Plugin zip file ADT-21.1.0.zip from 
   http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.1.0.zip
2. (do not unpack it):
3. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
4. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
5. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
6. Select the downloaded ADT-21.1.0.zip file and click OK.
7. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
8. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to
   Developer Tools and click Next.
9. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded.
   Click Next.
10. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
11. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or
     validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
12. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

---

- Resource:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
- Section:  Troubleshooting Installation

Answer (score 2):

Open `Eclipse -> Help -> Check for updates`

Eclipse will do the rest. Please make sure to restart Eclipse once the update is done for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Go to eclipse > help > Check for updates.

It should list the latest update of adt. If it doesn't work, try this :

go to eclipse > help > Install new software

Click on add

add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

It will list the updates available- which should ideally be adt 21.1.0 (latest)

install the latest adt and everything should be fine.

source: [Update ADT from 21.0 to 21.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951925/update-adt-from-21-0-to-21-1)
from inankupeli

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, do the following:

- On the menubar, go to: `Help -> Check for Updates`.
- Select ADT when the list comes up.
- Accept licenses when prompted.
- Click on Restart when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

Others answers are good.Adding to that

```
Eclipse -> help -> Install new software
```

click `What is already Installed`, then a list will come then select `Android Development tools`(i.e ADT) and click `update`.It will be updated to newer version.HTH :)

Comment: thanks, but my problem is it shows no updates and SDK is alone updated

Comment: As i said above try.when you will select "Android Development Tools" below will be four buttons update,Unistall,properties and close.Click on update,it will be automatically updated.

Comment: it will not show, it will be updated auromatically.any progress in bottom bar ?

Comment: Is it saying no updates found ? it is showing in my case.I dont know what u r doing thr

Comment: no i have changed to another sdk location which as sdk 0f 21.0 not 21.1 because as i told i have updated the sdk to 21.1 and where as adt was unable to update due to some other system problem and thanks again for your help.'